# How to obtain unnormalized responsibilities for GMM clusters?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, probability, mixture-model

I have trained a Gaussian Mixture Model with sklearn and I am trying to obtain the unnormalized responsibilities of a data point given the cluster means and variances.

`GMM.predict_proba` unfortunately returns the normalized probabilities such that they sum up to one but I need the raw ones.

I have tries the following (GMM is the fitted GM-model):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import mixture
lpr = (mixture.log_multivariate_normal_density(X, GMM.means_, GMM.covars_, GMM.covariance_type) + np.log(GMM.weights_))
probs = np.exp(lpr)
```

But the probabilities I obtained are bigger than 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please provide samples of `X` and `GMM`

Answer (score 0):

`lpr` is the log probabilities of the Gaussian components. To convert to the probability of GMM, sum of theses in log space should be performed. The following code will explain this.

```
from sklearn.utils.extmath import logsumexp

lpr = (mixture.log_multivariate_normal_density(X, GMM.means_, GMM.covars_, GMM.covariance_type) + np.log(GMM.weights_)) # probabilities of components
logprob = logsumexp(lpr, axis=1) # logsum to get probability of GMM
probs = np.exp(logprob) # 0 < probs < 1
```

Comment: Can you kindly tell how to find maximum likelyhood for each iteration while applying GMM.